# html to pdf viewer like lightbox?

Tags: php, html, pdf

Is there any way to generate a pdf view from html , just like we use light box to see images?

In simple words, i have a WYSIWYG editor and a button, all i want is that, after clicking on a button there should be a function which should convert html from editor and provide pop up having view in pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just send your html back to the server (maybe in ajax), and convert the html to pdf using something like [TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/) to convert html to pdf in php.